# SWIFT 3 How to connect Json from my localhost web service

Tags: json, swift, xml-parsing

I Would like to connect data from my localhost but there have error 
"json error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

> here is code.

```
 let session = URLSession.shared
 var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask!   
 var webDomain = "http://192.xxx.xx.xx:80xx/WebServiceTest.asmx"
 var url:URL!
 var arrTable = [[String:AnyObject]]()
 func getTableDataFromWeb(){
      strURL = webDomain + "/SearchNonMemberByRangeLatitude=25.062047&Longitude=121.495241&Range=300"
 url = URL(string: strURL)
 let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: strURL)!)
 let loginTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request,  completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in guard 
let data = data, let _ = response , error == nil else {
                                print("error")
                                return
                            }
                            do{
                                let arrayJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,options: .allowFragments)as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                self.arrTable = [arrayJSON]
                                print(self.arrTable)
                            }catch let error as NSError     {   print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")  }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            })
    print("Web：\(strURL)")
    loginTask.resume()
        }
```

> here is the Json data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://192.xxx.xx.xx:8081/WebServiceTest.asmx">[
[
        {
            "NonCID": "n10909",
            "Name": "xxx",
            "ClassType": "xxx",
            "City": "xxx",
            "Area": "xxx",
            "Address": "xxx",
            "TelArea": "xx",
            "Tel": "2xxxxx56",
            "Latitude": 2x.x047,
            "Longitude": 1xx.495241
        },

    ]</string>
```

> I also try XMlParse is work but get the data like this

```
Getting tag：string
Tag detail：["["]
Tag detail：["\n  {"]
Tag detail：["\n    \"NonCID\": \"n10909\","]
Tag detail：["\n    \"Name\": \""]
Tag detail：["1111\",\n    \"ClassType\": \"2222\",\n    \"City\": \"111\",\n    \"Area\": \"111\",\n    \"Address\": \"11111\",\n    \"TelArea\": \"02\",\n    \"Tel\": \"29857456\",\n    \"Latitude\": xx.062047,\n    \"Longitude\": 1xx.495241\n  },\n  {\n    \"NonCID\": \"n10957\",\n    \"Name\": \"xxx"]
Tag detail：["\",\n    \"ClassType\": \"xx\",\n    \"City\": \"xxx\",\n    \"Area\": \"xxx\",\n    \"Address\": \"xxxxx\",\n    \"TelArea\": \"02\"  }\n]"]
```

> Here is code

```
var tagName = String()
var tagContent = String()        
func getTableDataFromWeb()
            {
              strURL = webDomain + "/SearchNonMemberByRange?Latitude=2x.&Longitude=1xx.4x241&Range=300"
                url = URL(string: strURL)!
                dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (xmldata, response, error)
                    -> Void in
                    if xmldata == nil {
                        print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
                        return
                    }
                     let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: xmldata!)
                    xmlParser.delegate = self
                    xmlParser.parse()
                    print("Web：\(strURL)")
                    dataTask.resume()
                    }
        }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
        {
            if elementName == "NonCID"{
                tagName = elementName}
            print("Getting Tag：\(elementName)")
        }
        func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
        {
            tagContent = string
            arr = [tagContent]
            print("Tag Detail：\(arr)")
        }
        func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Can someone tell what should I to use Json data plz thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is XML. It just so happens that the text value of one of the XML elements in the XML file is JSON. So you need your XML parsing code to extract the JSON text. Then you need to use `JSONSerialization` on the extracted JSON.

Comment: sorry I don't understand could you give me some example for this case thanks:) @rmaddy